# Update MongoDB index failing on deployment

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

We have the following setup: we have a Spring Boot Backend deployed on AWS and initialize the MongoRepository via Spring. We are indexing some field by annotation

```
@Indexed(expireAfterSeconds = 43200)
private Date createdAt;
```

and are running now into the problem, that whenever we update an index, the build is failing because of

> "Index with name: createdAt already exists with different options"

I had the feeling, that before updating to *spring_data_mongo* *3.0.1.RELEASE*, we didn't have that problem, when deploying our application on AWS. Somebody has an idea, what I am missing?

Comment: What does [getIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) for the given collection yield?  You may be "amend" `@Indexed` for given `createdAt` to match the index spec.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I wasn't clear enough in my question, sorry for that! My problem is, that we had defined the index createdAt with a specific value for expireAfterSeconds, but now I want to change that setting or remove the index completely. I thought, there must be a way, that we can update the index in a database on deployment. Right now, the only choice I have is to manually drop the index so that on deployment it can create the adjusted one. But there must be a better automatic way?! Or is reIndex or drop index on application start the only solution, which would be quiet expensive?

Comment: according to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) : "You cannot use createIndex() to change the value of expireAfterSeconds of an existing index. Instead use the collMod database command in conjunction with the index collection flag. Otherwise, to change the value of the option of an existing index, you must drop the index first and recreate."